# Select related Elements Attributes as String

Tags: mysql, tags, sql

I have an items Table and a Tags table. Now what I would like is to have one Select that gets Items under a certain condition and for each item selects the related tags and puts them in a string to become a seperate field.

Example:

```
table_items:
id   | title
---------------------------
01   | peter
---------------------------
02   | john
---------------------------
03   | cindy

tags:
id   | title
---------------------------
01   | tall
---------------------------
02   | tiny
---------------------------
03   | blone
---------------------------
04   | loud
---------------------------
05   | ...

tags_to_items:
itemid | tagid
---------------------------
01     | 02
---------------------------
01     | 04
---------------------------
02     | 01
...
```

I think you get the point.

```
Now I want a result like this:
itemid | title   | tags
---------------------------
01     | peter   | tiny, loud
---------------------------
01     | john    | tall, fast, bored
```

Can I do this with just MySQL?
How?

Comment: look on group_concat function, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you need [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to do that.

Something like:

```
select ti.id, ti.title, group_concat(t.title)
  from table_items ti
 inner join tag_to_items tti on (ti.id = tti.itemid)
 inner join tags t on (t.id = tti.tagid)
 group by ti.id, ti.title
```